# Have a big problem. I installed Eclipse Helios, but I can't install the packages from dl-ssl.com/android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I installed the Eclipse Helios yesterday, because the Galileo threw me to the desktop a lot of time. I deleted it with it's file, and I downloaded Helios SR1. When I tried to Help -> Install new software... and wrote https://dl-ssl.com/android/eclipse, it showed to me the Developer Tools. I checked it, and I clicked on the Next button. It displayed me the following "error":

Your original request has been modified.
  "Android Development Tools" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android Hierarchy Viewer" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
  "Android DDMS" is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.

I tried to update them, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Android Tools?

In eclipse: Help.. About Eclipse... Installation Details. 
Then uninstall the Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, and Android Hierarchy Viewer

When you reinstall you'll need to again set the location of your Android SDK installation.
In eclipse: Window... Preferences... Android.
Paste in the SDK location (e.g. /opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/ ) and click apply and they should show up

Oh.. and you while you are at it.. You may as well change the location of the Eclipse site to 
http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ (ie change from https to http).
To be on the safe side

Comment: are you behind a proxy? Can you install other Eclipse plugins?

Comment: Its probably no harm to explain the solution here and mark it as the answer for other people who encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is reverting eclipse to the first configuration and then proceeding with the installation as usual.

Help->About->Installation History

Pick the earliest configuration and "Revert"

(Btw I'm using RAD so YMMV...)